# repository name in github desktop sidebar

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

The github Desktop program has an automatic naming scheme for local repositories, and I can't find a way to change them manually.

Consider this screenshot of the sidebar,

[image]

with 4 identical names, it's quite hard to navigate. Those folders are different copies (different branches, actually) of a common repository 'papers', under the 'plasmonics' organisation. Strangely, not all repositories of that organisation appear with the `plasmonics/` heading in the sidebar, and I can't tell what triggers a difference. In any case, I'm hoping to find a way to rename those sidebar names manually. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename those sidebar names, but do check if the issue persists with the new GitHub Desktop application ([released in Sept. 2017](https://blog.github.com/2017-09-19-announcing-github-desktop-1-0/), two years after your question)

It should be able to display/filter those repos correctly.
For local repos, make sure those copies are done through the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (Git 2.5 and more, from July 2015). That allows to clone a repo once, but check it out multiple times (one folder per branch).
There is a [pending issue (907)](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/907#issuecomment-344042654) for de-duplicating the display of those worktrees.